# SetY() on RecyclerView works strangely about inside items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to move (collapse or expand) a RecyclerView (which uses GridLayoutManager). So by default, I set the Y position of this list:

```
mListView.setY(XXXX);
```

The position works perfectly BUT some lines (at the bottom list) are not show. If I don't set Y all items are visible correctly.

Have you got some explanations?

Comment: How about adding the same value which used for setY for the setX too then checking?!

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท ?? which impact? I don't want to touch X position, only Y